# How to insert PHP into jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, insert

Here is my code to insert PHP into jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    if (<?php echo $story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName();?> == "Politics")
    {
        $("nav").addClass("politicsBG");
    }
    else if (<?php echo $story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName();?> == "Tech")
    {
        $("nav").addClass("techBG");
    }
});
```

Would you please show me why this code doesn't work? Thank you so much.

UPDATE. The jQuery is in a separated file. The jQuery above is the only thing I have in the JS file. Here is the code of my HTML. The categoryName (Politics, Tech) is printed out successfully in H1. So the output of data is correct. There is no error shown up. The background image just doesn't load. I tried not use PHP but only use `$("nav").addClass("techBG");` then the bg image loaded successfully.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Story.css">        
        <title>Ideatune</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Images/GeneralImages/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="../Images/GeneralImages/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../JQueryFile/Story.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav><!--                                    
            --><div class="navLeft"><!--
                --><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/logo.png"><!--
            --></div><!--                
            --><div class="navRight"><!--                                                                                                   
                --><ul><!--                                                                                                                                    
                    --><li class="notificationIcon"><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/notification.png" id="notificationLink"><!--
                        --><div class="dropdownContain"><!--
                            --><div class="dropOut"><!--
                                --><div class="triangle"></div><!--
                                --><div class="smalltriangle"></div><!--                               
                                --><ul><!--
                                    --><li>News 1</li><!--
                                    --><li>News 2</li><!--
                                    --><li>News 3</li><!--
            `       --><li>News 4</li><!--
                                --></ul><!--                               
                            --></div><!--                            
                        --></div><!--                                
                    --></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="javascript:alert('Hello');"><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/plus.png"></a></li><!--                                         
                --></ul><!--
                --><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/aunguyen-avatar.jpg" class="navAvatar"><!--       
            --></div><!--            
            --><div class="slogan"><!--
                --><h1><?php echo strtoupper($story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName());?></h1><!--                                                                                   
            --></div><!--                                                                                                                                        
        --></nav>
```

UPDATE 2
 Here is the error from the console

"Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
ReferenceError: blf is not defined

...];if (typeof(__tash) == 'undefined'){__tash={};} __tash.whi = new blf(array,10)

wl (line 1, col 99066)
2
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - ht//adadvisor.net/adscores/g.js?sid=9276253823"
g.js?si...6253823
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - ht//adadvisor.net/adscores/g.pixel?sid=9212192898&rf=1178043146693124497"
g.pixel...3124497
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - htt//adadvisor.net/adscores/g.js?sid=9276253823"
g.js?si...6253823
Error: Ad adLoadError error: VAST wrapper redirect unwrapping timeout. errorCode: 301
2
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - ht//adadvisor.net/adscores/g.pixel?sid=9212192898&rf=1178043146693124497"
g.pixel...3124497
Error: Ad adLoadError error: No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play. errorCode: 1001
Error: Ad adLoadError error: No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play. errorCode: 1001
Error: Ad adLoadError error: No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play. errorCode: 1001
8
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error."

Comment: What exactly is not working, are you getting any errors in js console? Post relevant HTML and php code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: what error you getting. what's the real code you getting after this code executed in browser. have you checked the source?

Comment: It is no different how you do in javascript, and your code seems to be fine apparently. Have you tried viewing the part where this is rendered in firebug?

Comment: `"Would you please show me why this code doesn't work?"` - Stack Overflow isn't a debugger.  Can you perhaps explain *how* it doesn't work?  What's broken?  Are you getting an error in your PHP logs?  If this page is rendering successfully, I suspect you're getting an error in your JavaScript console in the browser.  What is that error?  What is the actual JavaScript code which produces that error?

Answer (score 0):

Always look at the output. Example output might be:

```
if( Politics == "Politics")
```

Does that look right to you?

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode):

```
if( <?=json_encode($story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName())?> == "Politics")
```

If this doesn't work, then it's a problem with your data, not with how the data is passed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$out="$(document).ready(function ()
{";
    if ($story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName() == "Politics")
    {
        $out.="$('nav').addClass('politicsBG');";
    }
    else if ($story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName() == "Tech")
    {
        $out.="$('nav').addClass('techBG');";
    }
$out.="});";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Story.css">        
        <title>Ideatune</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Images/GeneralImages/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="../Images/GeneralImages/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav><!--                                    
            --><div class="navLeft"><!--
                --><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/logo.png"><!--
            --></div><!--                
            --><div class="navRight"><!--                                                                                                   
                --><ul><!--                                                                                                                                    
                    --><li class="notificationIcon"><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/notification.png" id="notificationLink"><!--
                        --><div class="dropdownContain"><!--
                            --><div class="dropOut"><!--
                                --><div class="triangle"></div><!--
                                --><div class="smalltriangle"></div><!--                               
                                --><ul><!--
                                    --><li>News 1</li><!--
                                    --><li>News 2</li><!--
                                    --><li>News 3</li><!--
            `       --><li>News 4</li><!--
                                --></ul><!--                               
                            --></div><!--                            
                        --></div><!--                                
                    --></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="javascript:alert('Hello');"><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/plus.png"></a></li><!--                                         
                --></ul><!--
                --><img src="../Images/GeneralImages/aunguyen-avatar.jpg" class="navAvatar"><!--       
            --></div><!--            
            --><div class="slogan"><!--
                --><h1><?php echo strtoupper($story->getStoryCategory()->getStoryCategoryName());?></h1><!--                                                                                   
            --></div><!--                                                                                                                                        
        --></nav>
...
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $out; ?>
</script>
</body>
```